# Correct handling of snmp INFORM by receiver

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I have some strage behaviour of SNMP4J which I can't explain. It is likely is due to my misunderstanding of snmp basics.

I deal with server which receives snmp traps. Everything is going on well. Now I need to change traps to inform.
The issue is my server is trying to handle received message twice. I occured with duplicating of INFORM message.

Trying to explain... I've enabled logger to DEBUG level. 
When INFORM is arrived I see in log file two same records from class **org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping.ListenThread** which has following code in **run()** method:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Received message from "+packet.getAddress()+"/"+
            packet.getPort()+
            " with length "+packet.getLength()+": "+
            new OctetString(packet.getData(), 0,
            packet.getLength()).toHexString());
}
```

Also I have class which implements interface **org.snmp4j.CommandResponder**. His method **void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent event)** is invoked twice for inform and once for a trap.

```
@Override
public void processPdu(final CommandResponderEvent evt) {
    final Address address = getAgentAddress(evt);
    final PDU command = evt.getPDU();
    boolean isInform = command.getType() == PDU.INFORM // this is true for both invocations of this method while receiving INFORM
}
```

Details about versions:
snmp v2, snmp4j version 2.3.0

Help me to realize: Does exist some bug here of I should filter second invocation of **processPdu** method by command.getRequestID(), for example?

Answer (score 3):

The INFORM must be acknowledged by Receiver.

I believe the problem is that the sender have not received the **RESPONSE PDU** back for this **INFORM REQUEST** for some reason. So it sends it once again according to the number of retries. Make sure you send **RESPONSE PDU** to the sender to confirm that you've received **REQUEST PDU (INFORM).** The API should do it for you. So make sure you call the default handler.